# How to load all images after 2 seconds in lazysizes?

Tags: javascript, lazysizes

I am lazy loading images on the page, using the [lazysizes](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) library I call the script at the beginning of the page

`<script> (function(){ window.lazySizesConfig = { lazyClass: 'lazy', loadMode: 2, hFac: 10, }; }); </script>`

But the question arose, how to make it so that after loading the page, after a couple of seconds, all the pictures on lazy loaded without waiting for the page to scroll?

I couldn’t find a suitable parameter in the documentation, or I don’t understand something

Comment: So if you want to eagerly load your images, why use lazy loading?

Comment: There are various reasons why one would want to load them all... In my case to save the page with Safari's > File > Export as PDF... without having to scroll to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually run through all your elements and load them using [unveil method](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/blob/gh-pages/README.md#lazysizesloaderunveildomnode)

```js
setTimeout(
    function () {
        $('.lazy').each(function () {
            lazySizes.loader.unveil($(this)[0])
        });
    },
    2000
);
```

Answer (score 0):

in Plain JS:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var lazyObj = window.lazySizes;
    // console.log(lazyObj);
    // Safari returns the Object as undefined!
    var isLazyObj = (typeof lazyObj !== 'undefined') ? true : false;
    var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img.lazy');
    imgs.forEach(function(img) {
        // console.log('unveil: ', img);
        if (isLazyObj) lazyObj.loader.unveil(img);
    })
}, 2000)
```

- Update: I found out my Safari (16.2) returns the `window.lazySizes` Object as *undefined* so I adjusted the snippet to check for this